# ReflectionTestUtils not working with MockitoJunitRunner

Tags: java, junit

Need is to write test case for a service. 
It initially uses value properties like :

```
@Value(#{"env.host"})
private String host;
```

I came across ReflectionTestUtils.setField and tried the same as below,with cloudImpl class with InjectMocks annotation:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(cloudImpl, "env.host", "localhost");
```

All i get is cannot find field "env.host" of type null in cloudImpl class. Could you please help figure out why ?

Answer (score 0):

The field name is "host", not "env.host". So you should use

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(cloudImpl, "host", "localhost");
```

Comment: it now says cannot find field host of type null :-\

Comment: just to be clear - CloudImpl class has a field called host, you make a mock instance of the class using @InjectMocks annotation and using it, it still says the field cannot be found? That should work. Perhaps you have a typo there? Can you try getting all the fields of the class and seeing the "host" indeed exists there?

Comment: i copied env variable and pasted in test. exactly the same. you are saying it right on my problem.

Comment: i don't get the last question

Comment: could you post a minimum complete example that has the behaviour you are observing?